# What is the difference between rate() and avg_over_time() function in promethues?

Tags: prometheus, average, monitoring, promql, rate

I have a metric (Counter) to get number of calls from specific caller and would want to compare with average of last hour 7 and 14 days before for one hr. Which function should I use to calculate the average number of calls made in last one hour. rate() or avg_over_time() ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function for calculating the number of calls over some duration for [counter metric](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter). For example, the following query returns the number of calls over the last hour for the counter `calls_total`:

```
increase(calls_total[1h])
```

If you want calculating the number of calls made for the last hour 7 days ago, then use `offset` modifier:

```
increase(calls_total[1h] offset 7d)
```

As for the [avg_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg_over_time) function, it is usually used for [gauge metrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#gauge).

P.s. Prometheus may return unexpected fractional results from `increase()` function applied to integer counter. This is because of extrapolation - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details. If you want obtaining the exact integer increase over the specified lookbehind window, then try [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - this is Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on.